# Hibernate Annotations: Two relation types between two entities?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, annotations

My scenario is a users table and a pictures table. Each user can upload multiple pictures. Each user can set one of their own pictures to be their favourite picture, but this does not affect that picture being within that user's collection of pictures.

Mapping this to hibernate has proven to be difficult. My application has a screen which displays a list of all of a user's pictures, and also says which one is their favourite. However, when the application loads the pictures, the single picture which is the favourite one does not load. Debugging in eclipse shows various fun things for that specific object in the list, perhaps it is a proxy object. Here is the entity code showing the mappings:

```
@Entity
class Account {
    @Id
    public String username;

    /* Originally a Set<Picture>, but wanted ordering */
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="account")
    @OrderBy("uploadtime DESC")
    public List<Picture> pictures;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name="favourite_picture_id")
    public Picture favourite_picture;

    /* Sometimes it is useful to get just the id, if possible without loading the entire entity */
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public String favourite_picture_id;
}

@Entity
public class Picture {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy="uuid2")
    public String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="username")
    public Account account;

    /* This is never used, but I thought this might be required for the mapping? */
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="favourite_picture")
    public Account account_favourite_picture;


    public String mimetype;

    public Date uploadtime = new Date();

    @Column(length=1024 * 1024 * 4)
    public byte[] data;
}
```

I do not know why the favourite picture fails to load in the list of pictures. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `Picture` has a specific `Account` which owns it I would be tempted just to include a boolean property on the Picture class called `isFavourite`. This would simplify the mappings considerably.

You could provide a `getFavourite` method on the Account class which returns the favourite picture by looking through the list of pictures and finding the one marked as favourite.

Comment: That's an interesting way to fix the problem. I'm using a List<Picture> mapping because I expect a small number of pictures per account, so it might be acceptable. Perfectionism can't get in the way of having a functional system.

You've inspired another idea too, I could have a string in the Account entity to store the ID of the favourite picture, and I could implement a getFavourite() method in Account, which goes through the list to find the matching picture. This is probably what I will do unless there's a better post soon. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: No problem. Complex mappings are something which I aim to avoid if at all possible. I would always prefer to simpler approach!

Comment: Simple really is best, it's all working now with the simpler mapping.